# Add params from file to given URL in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to generate a series of urls using given urls plus some params in a txt file.

For example, the given urls are:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask2
```

They are stored in A1, A2, respectively, in Sheet1 in url.xlsx file.

The params are stored in params.txt file, with following content:

```
w3e
1
123456
fy
```

I would like to generate urls like following:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1/param.x
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask2/param.x
```

This means I will get 2x4=8 urls.

Any idea how to make this work? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read both files into lists, then use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to combine them:

```
from itertools import product

with open('urls.txt') as urlfile:
    urls = [line.strip() for line in urlfile]
```

with open('params.txt') as paramfile:
        parameters = [line.strip() for line in paramfile]

```
for url, param in product(urls, parameters):
    print url + param
```